# Changing columns to row using awk

Tags: awk

I have this list:

```
AA 1
AA 2
AA 3
B 4
B 4
C 5
C 6
C 7
C 8
```

and I want to change it to below output using awk:

```
AA 1 2 3
B 4 4
C 5 6 7 8
```

Could you please let me know how can I do this using AWK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key an array `rec` by the 1st field, store the 2nd field in the array, and finally sort the results.

```
awk '{ rec[$1]=rec[$1] " " $2 }
END { for (key in rec) print key rec[key] }
' file.txt | sort
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] FS $2} END{for(i in a) print i a[i]}' file
```

Output:

```
AA 1 2 3
B 4 4
C 5 6 7 8
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56716292/3776858

---

And again in the other direction:

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1,$i}}' file
```

Comment: Thanks alot, really appreciated.